# AngularJS ng-show="{{show}}" do not have 2 way binding

Tags: angularjs

Here , I am trying to show the pagignation based on the number of items. 
if number of items is more than 5 than it should show, other it should hide
the pagination.

```js
 $scope.do = { showPaging: false };
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <ul uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" boundary-links="true"
 items-per-page="itemsPerPage" class="pagination-sm" ng-show="{{do.showPaging}}"></ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-show="{{show}}"
```

do not have 2 way binding  while

```
ng-show="show"
```

have 2 way binding.